# How to gracefully terminate an app on Android emulator with Eclipse (on Mac)

Tags: android, emulation, terminate

I am trying to end my app gracefully on an Android emulator without causing a crash or killing the app.

Having read numerous posts on how to terminate or crash an app on Android, here's what I've tried:

- Switched the emulator to another app
- Clicked the Hang up on call button and Make a call button on the emulator
- Added finish(); System.exit(0); to my onPause event in the app
- Clicked on the root of my program in the Debug perspective in Eclipse and clicked the red square on the menu icon row to terminate, did same and disconnected as well.

Each time I start up the app after any of the above, the tracking code is considering the above chosen method a crash.

So I'm trying to figure out how to gracefully end my app and restart it without incurring a 'crash'.

Any ideas?

Big thanks

Comment: First and second actions should NOT cause a crash and is normal Android app behavior.

Comment: A good question would be: what is your tracking code? Even killing the app with a task manager or while reinstalling shouldn't be handled as a crash.